# Webgl - Three js performance

Tags: performance, three.js, load, webgl

Hy!
I am working in webgl using three js, huge meshes also convert them to JSON format and show them on the screen at the end I have had 700 000+ vertices at a time, was laggish but possible. I have figured it out how i can split and export lots of smaller modells from my huge one. And when I tried to show the same modell, but this time using smaller objects some of the objects showed up, but after the browser crashed.

So my question is is there a limit on javascript arrays, or simply I cannot work with modells like this.

My first idea is to parse more vertice(merge modells) into a single file, and find the golden middleway.
What do you think?

**----UPDATE----**

Ok so I find it out why I'm not be able to show the same modell with smaller objects(meshes).
Seems the problem is with javascript arrays. I'm running some tests to figure it out.

Older version(smaller meshes stored in 1 array):

```
var objects = [];
```

crash around ~8k objects

Testing Version(smaller meshes stored in 4 arrays):

```
    var objects1 = [];
    var objects2 = [];
    var objects3 = [];
    var objects4 = [];
```

Ok it doesen't matter like this I crashed ~7k objects.

The solution will be to edit the modells and import them in bigger groups and find the "Middle Golden Way"...

Comment: You can run out of memory in the browser. I'm not sure what the limti is

Comment: Yes I know that. I'm working on optimizations now, loading 1 modell at a time, also showing limited number of modells etc.